# Automate git commit of multiple files

Tags: git, batch-file, command-line, git-commit

I have a collection of files that I want to automatically add and commit to git using a batch script.
Adding is not a big problem as I can add them all indiviually. But I don't want to commit them individually because this cluters the git repository with commits.

One way would be:

```
git commit -a -m ...
```

which would commit everything. But this is also not very practical as I would commit other files that I don't necessarily want to commit.

The files that I want to commit are found by:

```
dir <some_path> /b /s /A-D /o:gn
```

**Is there a way to put this list of files into the git commit command?**

Full script:

```
>  FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir <some_path> /b /s /A-D /o:gn') do CALL git add %%a -f

> git commit (Some list of files) -m <Some message>
```

The obvious way would be to just replace `(Some list of files)` with `('dir <some_path> /b /s /A-D /o:gn')`but this produces an error: `fatal: /b: '/b' is outside repository`

How can I achieve what I want?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Not sure what exactly the question is here, as you start by stating that adding them is not the problem, and then go on to show that you can't figure out how to properly add them. Can you clarify?

Comment: _"as I would commit other files that I don't necessarily want to commit"_ what classifies them as not candidates for committing and also not present in `.gitignore`?

Comment: I want to have a batch file that can read out a collection of files and commit them together with one single message. Adding is no problem as i can just loop over them. But looping and commiting results in many single commits which I want to avoid. Therefore I want to automatically put a list of files into the git commit command and commit them together. However, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't want to commit files that are not on the specified list. Possibly because I am still working on those other files.

Comment: The first thing to mention is that there seems no need to group directories first when sorting items specifically without the directory attribute!. What you appear to be trying to achieve is to list the files returned by `dir` concatenated into one line, instead of several. Is that what you're tryng to ask? You should find several questions and answers on this site which does that, although it may be easier to search for removing line or carriage returns, The majority of those answers will use `set /p` to assist with that. The search facility is available at the top of each page.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to ask. How to put a list of files concatenated in the git commit command in the way git wants it.

Comment: Well there you go, I've provided some information to assist you with your research. This site doesn't do your research for you, provide links for you to do your own from, or write your code for you, so please use the search facility to put together enough code for us to be able to assist you with it. We cannot help you to fix something you haven't tried and failed with. You also need to be aware that there are character length limits on lines and the environment for variables, so it would be prudent to ensure that your intent or resulting solution does not potentially exceed those.

Answer (score 2):

`git commit` will usually commit all files in the index (so all files you previously added to the list of changes for next commit with `git add`).

Therefore you do **not** have to specify the filenames after `git commit`.

If you're afraid that other files are already in the index before you run git add, you could run `git reset -- .` at the very beginning of your script.

This will undo any past `git add` commands that were not committed yet, making sure you start your own `git add`s on a clean index.

PS: None of these commands will change any files, they will just change whether or not they are considered for the commit.

Comment: Thanks, git reset is probably an easier solution than specifying the individual files.

Answer (score 0):

As others, I am a bit confused with your terminology :

there is a `git add` action, which adds to the index, and "waits" until you issue `git commit`

The script would simply be :

```
git add file1
git add file2
...
git add fileN
# no need to pass a list of files there :
git commit -m ...
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The tool that I am building should automatically add a specified group of files and then commit them in one commit. I don't want to commit files that are not specified which would happen with simply git commit -m

Comment: There definitely is a misunderstanding. "-m" only serves to provide the commit message from the command line. In the above example, only files `1 .. N` will be committed, in one single commit. Have a closer look at the docs, and try the commands out on your repo.